# How to sent the Ctrl+Alt+Del key combination via iTerm2?

Tags: iterm

We use the Apple "Pro Keyboard", which is a USB keyboard with model number M7803, and iTerm2 build 1.0.0 with "ipmitool sol activate" running.

Our goal is to sent the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> key combination to the remote host.

We tried this by: iTerm > Preferences > Keys > [+]:

- Keyboard Shortcut: ⌃⌥Del→
- Action: [ Send Hex Code ]
- Hex code: 1d 38
  53 b8 9d

This configuration does not sent the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination to the remote host, Debian 6.0.6 running kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP, at least the machine does not reboot as it would do when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on a local attached keyboard.

How to issue a reboot command on the remote machine using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination via iTerm?

Comment: Usually you can do this just on the local console and not remotely. Which system do you have on the other side?

Comment: Debian 6.0.6 running kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP

Comment: Any reason why you are not just typing "reboot"? In any case take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/50277/send-ctrl-alt-del-over-ssh

Comment: @Matteo We don't type reboot because there is no prompt in the GRUB2 version 1.99 menu.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to connect to the host before the system is loaded and the Grub menu is present? How do you connect to the remote host?

Comment: @Matteo: We connect via Serial Over LAN as described in the question with the partial command "ipmitool sol activate".

Comment: OK I missed that ...